# Resize an image that is in a button

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a button with an image inside, but I want to adjust the size of this image, how can I adjust the size of the image?
I'm trying to make my image 150 points high, but I do not know how to do it programmatically

[image]

Comment: How are you creating your UI? Are you using storyboards or doing it programmatically?

Comment: @HAK i am using storyboards

Comment: And how are you setting your images? Dynamically?

Comment: @HAK no, I'm placing my image with the property of the buttons, the property image

Comment: Cant you use UIImageView instead of buttons. UIImageView has a property to fit the image with respect to the aspect ratio so the image won't stretch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best possible approach would be to regenerate the image asset at the appropriate size you need it (using photoshop, preview, etc) and then use that instead.

Another option, in the storyboard switch to the ruler tab and adjust the image insets.

[image: image insets]

Yet another approach would be to use a UIImageView and add a UITapGestureRecognizer to it to detect a tap. Then you can configure the image view with constraints and set up the aspect ratio. The downside here is that you lose the stateful changes of the button when it is pressed/depressed so it won't look as good. I wouldn't add an imageview as a subview of a button either, that can create strange problems.

One thing I'd like to add is that resizing images can be expensive.  If you are loading these buttons into a tableview then you need to be careful not to accidentally resize the images as the cells are enqueued/dequeued. This will block the main thread and cause smooth scrolling issues.

Answer (score 0):

When you set a button’s image it will have an `imageView` property containing the image. Therefore, you can set the imageView’s `contentMode` property to `.scaleAspectFit` to keep the image proportions after resizing:

```
button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

The actual resizing can be done in InterfaceBuilder using layout constraints, for example.

However, if you know the button target size at compile time, you should make sure the image already has the desired size instead of sizing a wrongly-sized image at runtime.